# Cache problem old images - Magento 1.9

Tags: cache

In logs i found this

> media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/800x800/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95
>   /p/a/_lindt_2132.jpg

it's an old image.
I checked in: `var/cache` the cache is deleted and rewrite correctly.

Does Magento write the information of image in db? Is there a way to delete definition the old image?

Why are there old images in `/media/tmp/catalog/product/`

Thanks

Comment: Please try removing image cache by traversing to system->cache management->Flush catalog  image cache and flush swatch image cache.

Comment: Did you check the referrer for that image request? Is that image referenced in a page served by your Magento store?